# Adicionar classe em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso que o código abaixo funcione via classe e não via função está assim:

```
<input oninput="mascara(this)" type="text">
```

e preciso que funcione via `class`, assim:

```
<input class="minhafuncao" type="text">
```

como alterar o código abaixo:

```
<input oninput="mascara(this)" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mascara(i){       
        var v = i.value;   
        if(isNaN(v[v.length-1])){
            i.value = v.substring(0, v.length-1);
            return;
        }   
        i.setAttribute("maxlength", "14");
        if (v.length == 1 || v.length == 0) 
            i.value += ".";
        if (v.length == 11) 
        i.value += "-";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Par mim não faz o sentido sua pergunta. É como se você quisesse usar uma classe javascript como se fosse um atributo *HTML class*, é um equivoco. Talvez não tenha entendido, poderia esclarecer?

Comment: Ola Cario, por favor faça um [tour] pela plataforma para aprender melhor em como formular sua pergunta. Aqui no SO nos ajudamos as pessoas a resolverem problemas, o que voce esta pedindo é para alguém fazer o seu trabalho por voce, por favor, coloque qual a sua duvida e tambem coloque o codigo que voce ja tentou e nao funcionou.

Comment: Assim, entendi perfeitamente. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pelo oque entendi você quer ao inves de utilizar uma função direta no elemento, criar um evento através da class.

```
<input class="minhafuncao" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.minhafuncao').on('change', function() {
        var v = this.value;   
        if(isNaN(v[v.length-1])){
            i.value = v.substring(0, v.length-1);
            return;
        }   
        i.setAttribute("maxlength", "14");
        if (v.length == 1 || v.length == 0) 
            i.value += ".";
        if (v.length == 11) 
        i.value += "-";
    });
</script>
```

Não me atentei ao código que você executou e sim pela maneira que você pode executar funções através de um seletor.
Segue o link da documentação do [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/on/).